# Strange variation on "DDL has a SelectedValue which is invalid because it does not exist in the list of items"

Tags: asp.net

Using an `asp:DropDownList` with `OnDataBound="PageDDL_DataBound"` ...

```
    protected void PageDDL_DataBound(Object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        PageDDL.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem("BACK", "0"));
        PageDDL.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem("-- Select Page --", "none"));
        PageDDL.SelectedIndex = -1;

        if (linkEnt != null && (LinkType)Convert.ToInt16(linkEnt.LinkTypeValue) == LinkType.InternalLink)
        {
            if (PageDDL.Items.FindByValue(linkEnt.LinkValue) != null)
            {
                PageDDL.SelectedValue = linkEnt.LinkValue;
            }
        }
    }
```

An exception is thrown (not from within this code) when the `linkEnt.LinkValue` is "0".
Note `PageDDL.SelectedValue` is not changed anywhere else in code.

Anyone?

Comment: What is `linkEnt`? _What_ exception is thrown and from where?

Comment: @TimSchmelter - Exception is mentioned in the title of the question :) and what I can get from his description, exception is being thrown on this line PageDDL.SelectedValue = linkEnt.LinkValue;

Comment: `linkEnt` is just an object of one of our own classes - it's not important. The property `LinkValue` is a `String` which, in this case returns "0" (any other value it returns does not cause the exception). As you can see from the code, a `ListItem` with value "0" has literally just been added to the `PageDDL.Items` list.

Comment: Visual studio does not break on the exception (even configuring break on every possible type of thrown exception), so I don't know for sure where it is thrown. It's not on the line `PageDDL.SelectedValue = linkEnt.LinkValue`.

Answer (score 0):

I think putting all this code outside the databound event can work.
I don't see any need of `DataBound` event for your code, or there is?

For databound event you should be binding something with the dropdownlist and then have to call dropdownlist's `Databind()` event that will call `DataBound` event for each item added.

And I think it is throwing the exception because when you are trying to set the selected value, the dropdown list is not fully bound with the items so it can't find that item.

Comment: We are binding to a DB datasource. This code in the `OnDataBound` event is because we're adding two entries to the start of the list for values that will not be in the datasource.

Comment: We are binding, in the markup, to a datasource. The `Databound` event is fired only when the binding is complete from [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.basedataboundcontrol.ondatabound.aspx) "This method notifies a server control that any data binding logic associated with the control has completed."

Answer (score 0):

Try to call `PageDDL.Items.Clear();` first.

Maybe it is a bug:

[Microsoft Connect - ASP.NET DropDownList SelectedValue is persisted which results in exception if the control is DataBound second time](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/666808/asp-net-dropdownlist-selectedvalue-is-persisted-which-results-in-exception-if-the-control-is-databound-second-time)

Comment: It sounds like it it's related to that bug, but certainly can't add `PageDDL.Items.Clear()` in this method as that would remove all of the items that were bound to the list from the datasource. Have tried using `PageDDL.ClearSelection()` but that doesn't help.

Comment: @user2026032: Have you `AppendDataBoundItems=true`? You could also load the databound items and add them manually.

Comment: We have `AppendDataBoundItems` set to false - don't want the list containing multiple copies on reload. Might try and load the databaound items in code - just to see if the same thing happens (I suspect it will). We have another solution, but it's not very satisfying (can't post it yet) ... would like to know why this is happening.

Answer (score 0):

The following code works in this case

```
    protected void PageDDL_DataBound(Object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        PageDDL.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem("[BACK]", "0"));
        PageDDL.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem("-- Select [BACK] or a Page  --", "none"));
        PageDDL.SelectedIndex = -1;

        if (linkEnt != null && (LinkType)Convert.ToInt16(linkEnt.LinkTypeValue) == LinkType.InternalLink)
        {
            ListItem item = PageDDL.Items.FindByValue(linkEnt.LinkValue);
            if (item != null)
            {
                item.Selected = true;
            }
        }
    }
```

I would dearly love to know why it does, but the original code doesn't!!